# How to make a toplink active when clicked on it in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to make my topmenu link active when clicked on it.It contains `Home, Specials(category name),About Us(cms page),FAQ(cms page) and Contact us`.I want that when i clicked on any of the upper link,that link will be active.I used one class "active-1" for that.I want any condition to make the toplink active when clicked on it.
the code used in `topmenu.phtml` page whick make you easy to understand.

```
<style>
.nav-container ul.somelink li.active-1 a{ background:#fa9c04;}
</style>
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php $page_route=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); ?>
<?php $pageID = Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getIdentifier();?>
<div class="nav-container">
<ul class="somelink">
<li <?php if($pageID=="home") echo 'class="active-1"';?> ><a href="
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>">Home</a></li>
<li <?php if($pageID=="specials.html") echo 'class="active-1"';?>><a href="
<?php echo $this->getUrl('specials.html') ?>">Specials</a></li>
<li <?php if($pageID=="about-us") echo 'class="active-1"';?>><a href="
<?php echo $this->getUrl('about-us') ?>">About Us</a></li>
<li <?php if($pageID=="faq") echo 'class="active-1"';?>><a href="
<?php echo $this->getUrl('faq') ?>">FAQ</a></li>
<li <?php if($page_route=="contacts") echo 'class="active-1"';?>><a href="
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>contacts">contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

the above code works but when i am clearing the cache,then the menu will be active,it is not active at that time i have to clear the cache again and again for making the menu active

Comment: I used below coding, it is not working please help me it is very urgent

Comment: plese see the above coding and tell me where i am commiting mistake

Answer (score 3):

I usually do it from css.
So have the menu like you have it, but add some classes to each item:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="somelink"> 
       <li><a class="home-link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">Home</a></li>
       <li><a class="specials-link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('specials.html') ?>">Specials</a></li>
        <li><a class="about-link"  href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('about-us') ?>">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a class="faq-link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('faq') ?>">FAQ</a></li>
         <li><a class="contact-link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts') ?>">Contact Us</a></li>   

    </ul>
</div>
```

Since every magento page has a different class on the `<body>` element you can use that.

Add the following to your css file. (replace `color:red` with the properties that highlight your menu item)

```
.cms-index-index .home-link { /* for homepage*/
    color:red; 
}
.cms-specials .specials-link { /*for specials page */
    color:red
}
....
```

As a general rule, visit every page in your menu, get the specific class from the body and add a line like this to the css

```
.[body-class-here] .[link-to-be-selected-class-here] {
    color:red
}
```

An alternative for the 1.7+ version would be to add the menu items directly in the top menu using the `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` event. When adding a menu item, the item supports an 'active' property, where you can put the code to make the link active.

[See this for more info](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this will help's u, try this,

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php $page_route=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); ?>
<?php $pageID = Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getIdentifier();?>
<div class="nav-container">
<ul class="somelink"> 
   <li <?php if($pageID=="home") echo 'class="active"';?> ><a href="
<?php echo    Mage::getBaseUrl();?>">Home</a></li>
   <li <?php if($pageID=="specials.html") echo 'class="active"';?>><a href="
<?php echo   $this->getUrl('specials.html') ?>">Specials</a></li>
    <li <?php if($pageID=="about-us") echo 'class="active"';?>><a  href="
<?php echo $this->getUrl('about-us') ?>">About Us</a></li>
     <li <?php if($pageID=="faq") echo 'class="active"';?>><a href="
<?php echo    $this->getUrl('faq') ?>">FAQ</a></li>
     <li <?php if($page_route=="contacts") echo 'class="active"';?>><a href="
<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl();?>contacts">contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

And add active class like this .nav-container ul li.active(color:red);

Comment: no it is not working...i used the same coding and in style i wrote .nav-container ul li.active{
 background:#fa9c04;} then also nothing came

Comment: plz click contact us link and let me know it is active or not..?

Comment: plz give the correct page identifier here..  <?php if($pageID=="<page identifier>")

Comment: @Prince u should add this. because this will get the page identifier.
<?php $page_route=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); ?>

<?php $pageID = Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getIdentifier();?>

Comment: ya i have already added......I used the correct identifier also..here
Home-home,Specials-specials.html,About Us-about-us,Contact Us-contacts

Comment: you please tried the code in your demo file and if it will work then plz send the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52180/discussion-between-prince-kumar-and-skp)